# How to get a running total in python

Tags: python, cumulative-sum

I am learning how to code at the moment and am wondering how to get a running total. i have the code to do basic calculator functions and now want to learn how to get the calculator to be able to do multiple problems at once with the previous answer ex.(5 + 5 = 10 - 5 = 5 * 5 = 25 / 5) = 5. i want the user to be able to do as many problems with the previous result as he or she wants, but can exit at any time, as well. i am using python and would really like if someone could help assist/point me in the right direct as to what i need to code to get this to happen. i am not looking for an answer, just some help. thank you.

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y    

print "Lets Calculate" 

print ("Calculator: ")
print ("1: +")
print ("2: -")
print ("3: *")
print ("4: /")
print ("5: done")

foo1 = input("math solution: ")
num1 = float(raw_input("number 1: "))
num2 = float(raw_input("number 2: ")) 

if foo1 == 1:
    print "{0} + {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, add(num1, num2)) 
elif foo1 == 2:
    print "{0} - {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, subtract(num1, num2))
elif foo1 == 3:
    print "{0} * {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, multiply(num1, num2))
elif foo1 == 4:
    print "{0} / {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, divide(num1, num2))
elif foo1 == 5:
    print ("done")
```

result:

```
Lets Calculate                                                                                                                                                                                        
Calculator:                                                                                                                                                                                           
1: +                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2: -                                                                                                                                                                                                  
3: *                                                                                                                                                                                                  
4: /  
5: done                                                                                                                                                                                               
math solution: 1                                                                                                                                                                                      
number 1: 2                                                                                                                                                                                           
number 2: 2                                                                                                                                                                                           
2.0 + 2.0 = 4.0
```

i want to have the option to take that answer and use other math solutions with it before finishing. thank you in advance.

here is what i got. ive tried a million different things and cant figure it out.

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y    

print "Lets Calculate" 

print ("Calculator: ")
print ("1: +")
print ("2: -")
print ("3: *")
print ("4: /")
print ("5: done")

foo1 = input("math solution: ")
rec1 = 0

num1 = float(raw_input("number 1: "))  
while foo1 > 0 and foo1 < 6:
    num2 = float(raw_input("number 2: ")) 

    if foo1 == 1:
        rec1 =  "{0} + {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, add(num1, num2)) 
    elif foo1 == 2:
        rec1 = "{0} - {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, subtract(num1, num2))
    elif foo1 == 3:
        rec1 = "{0} * {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, multiply(num1, num2))
    elif foo1 == 4:
        rec1 = "{0} / {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, divide(num1, num2))
    elif foo1 == 6:
        rec1 = "Done" 
    print rec1

    foo2 = input("math solution: ")

print "done"
```

i added the num1 = rec1 and an error message pops up every time i try and move on to the next problem. i edited the code so you can see what it looks like now.

```
    def add(x, y):
    return x + y
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y    

print "Lets Calculate" 

print ("Calculator: ")
print ("1: +")
print ("2: -")
print ("3: *")
print ("4: /")
print ("5: done")

foo1 = input("math solution: ")
rec1 = 0

num1 = float(raw_input("number 1: "))
while foo1 > 0 and foo1 < 6:
    num2 = float(raw_input("number 2: ")) 

    if foo1 == 1:
        rec1 =  "{0} + {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, add(num1, num2)) 
    elif foo1 == 2:
        rec1 = "{0} - {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, subtract(num1, num2))
    elif foo1 == 3:
        rec1 = "{0} * {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, multiply(num1, num2))
    elif foo1 == 4:
        rec1 = "{0} / {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, divide(num1, num2))
    elif foo1 == 6:
        rec1 = "Done"
    print rec1

    num1 = rec1
    foo1 = input("math solution: ")

print "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

For continue until the user chooses to exit, you could use a loop, something like:

```
foo1 = input("math solution: ")

while foo1 > 0 and foo1 < 5:
   num1 = float(raw_input("number 1: "))
   num2 = float(raw_input("number 2: ")) 
   ....
   # Ask for the next operation
   foo1 = input("math solution: ")

print "done"
```

Second point, you want to use the previous result. What you could do is to store it into a variable, and then print it, instead of directly printing it.

Something like:

```
ans = 0
if foo1 == 1:
    ans = ...
elif foo1 == 2:
    ans = ...
print ans
```

And finally, for allowing to the user, we could use a little trick. For example, if the user writes 'ans' in the input, it will be the last result.

For doing this, we can process the input string before casting it to a float:

```
num1 = raw_input("number 1: ")
if num1 == 'ans':
   num1 = ans
else:
   num1 = float(num1)
```

I haven't written the entire piece of code for allowing you to play with that and figure out how to put everything together. However, if you need it tell me! :)

## Edit

In case you always want to use the previous one, one we could do is to initialize one input before the loop:

```
num1 = float(raw_input("number 1: "))
while foo1 > 0 and foo1 < 5:
   num2 = float(raw_input("number 2: ")) 
   ....
```

And then, at the end:

```
   # Store the result
   num1 = ans
   # Ask for the next operation
   foo1 = input("math solution: ")
print "done"
```

## Edit 2

You forget to implement part of this block:

```
ans = 0
if foo1 == 1:
    ans = ...
elif foo1 == 2:
    ans = ...
print ans
```

Of course, if you are storing the result as the output string, you cannot operate with it.

A correct version could be:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y    

print "Lets Calculate" 

print ("Calculator: ")
print ("1: +")
print ("2: -")
print ("3: *")
print ("4: /")
print ("5: done")

result = 0

# Ask for the operation and for the first number
operation = input("math solution: ")
num1 = float(raw_input("number 1: "))

# Continue until the user chooses to exit
while 0 < operation < 5:

    # Ask for the second number
    num2 = float(raw_input("number 2: ")) 

    # Operate
    if operation == 1:
        result = add(num1, num2)
        print "{0} + {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, result)
    elif operation == 2:
        result = subtract(num1, num2)
        print "{0} - {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, result)
    elif operation == 3:
        result = multiply(num1, num2)
        print "{0} * {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, result)
    elif operation == 4:
        result = divide(num1, num2)
        print "{0} / {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, result)

    # Store the result as the first number
    num1 = result

    # Ask for the next operation
    operation = input("math solution: ")

# Finish
print "Done"
```

Trace:

```
Lets Calculate
Calculator: 
1: +
2: -
3: *
4: /
5: done
math solution: 1
number 1: 10
number 2: 5
10.0 + 5.0 = 15.0
math solution: 2
number 2: 7
15.0 - 7.0 = 8.0
math solution: 3
number 2: 8
8.0 * 8.0 = 64.0
math solution: 4
number 2: 4
64.0 / 4.0 = 16.0
math solution: 5
Done
```

Comment: okay, i got everything work except the running total. i cannot seem to wrap my brain around how to get the previous total to calculate into the next equation. more help please. Álvaro Reneses

Comment: At the end of the loop, it is not `foo2 = input("math solution: ")` but `foo1 = input("math solution: ")`

Comment: i accidentally left that, because i was messing around with the code. it still does not allow me to take the total from the previous problem and add it to the next math problem. this just lets me keep the first number the same, where i want the first number to be the total from the first problem.

Comment: You forgot to add this part `num1 = ans`, or in your case, `num1 = rec1`. Without it you are having num1 being the same all the time.

Comment: i added the num1 = rec1 and an error message pops up every time i try and move on to the next problem. i edited the code so you can see what it looks like now.